# How to install OpenLayers in drupal?

Tags: 7, installation, javascript

I have been trying this for a while without success. After installing the OpenLayers module in drupal 7.14 and trying to configure it i get the following error:

Cannot establish a connection to the server:

I have tried all permutations including downloading the openlayers library in the local machine, giving it a local path in a number of different ways.

The second error that is seen suggests that i am installing an incorrect version of the openlayers library when in fact i have been installing the recommended version i.e. version 2.11.

It has been a frustrating experience getting Openlayers, Geoserver , PostGIS and Drupal 7 working together on Windows 7. The number of combinations are many and there are many issues that are difficult to solve if you are not a webmaster.

Comment: Are you able to view your apache server's error log?  Or are you using IIS?

Comment: no i am using apache, i will check apache's log

Comment: [Thu Jun 07 14:15:08 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/drupal/admin, referer: http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/structure/openlayers
[Thu Jun 07 14:15:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/drupal/admin, referer: http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/structure/openlayers

Comment: The error logs suggest that the installation process cannot find the javascript library although the path is correct

Comment: Can you enable Clean URLs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726439/clean-urls-not-working-in-drupal-7 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/missing-clean-urls-option
I believe that will get rid of the error. It looks like you do not have clean urls enabled and something is trying to direct your browser to localhost/drupal/admin instead of localhost/drupal/?q=admin

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for the '?q' URL problem which occurs using openlayers-7.x-2.0-beta1, apply the openlayers-fix-marker-lang-path-1404912-3.patch (http://drupal.org/node/1404912) it should fix this for you.